# Binding data to RequestBody (415 error)

Tags: java, spring

I have the following in my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@RequestBody UserEntity request) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getId());
        return "register";
    }

}
```

The `UserEntity` is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
```

I get the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Note that I have Jackson installed (from this question: [Jackson Databind classpath issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419160/jackson-databind-classpath-issue)).

Additionally, I am able to use the `public String registerUser(HttpServletRequest request)` fine, but when I try using `@RequestBody` it just gives me that error.

How would I get the @RequestBody to be the UserEntity?

Comment: your setup seems to be correct ignoring the fact that a proper entity definition doesnt look like that, what are you `POST`ing as JSON from the client to the the `registerUser` method ?

Comment: @dashboard updated question above.

Comment: okay, are you setting the `Content-Type` header of your request to be `application/json` ? Because spring in the background uses Jackson to bind your JSON data to your POJO. Let me know when you checked that.

Comment: Try adding `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` (or similar) to your resource method.  I'm guessing Jackson can't figure out how to parse the incoming request body since you haven't specified what it should expect.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese what do I need to import to use the `@Consumes` decorator?

Comment: @dashboard note that I'm getting POST data directly from the html form, and so it's not json -- do you think this is the issue?

Comment: @David542 Actually maybe it's better to do something like this: `@PostMapping(value="/register", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: @David542 Also if you're getting it from html then try `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`

Comment: That might be, since the form data possibly has the header of type `www-form-encoded` it's failing to infer the content type. how about using `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)` annotation as @ChocolateAndCheese suggests ?

Comment: Essentially that 415 status code is letting you know that the server can't figure out what format the data is in, so you need to configure the endpoint so that it is expecting the format that the website is sending it

Comment: it's clear that this is a content-type mismatch error. At best I recommend you to use your browser's Network tab from the Developer Tools (F12 key on Chrome and Firefox) then analyze the request headers of your POST AJAX request. Then, make a little search for the corresponding spring-data MediaType for it.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese @dashboard -- thanks for both of your help on this. It seems like this is the answer: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-form-urlencoded-data. Which directory would I put the web.xml file? Is that in `resources` ?

Comment: well the documentation says  `...To support HTTP PUT and PATCH requests...` before the web.xml part and I don't think you need this. Please don't just blindly copy-paste every suggestion. Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782025/http-post-request-with-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-not-workin/38252762)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the header value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" in the request while you should use "application/json"