# Way to save a @Requestbody object directly to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a `UserEntity` object from a registration form. Here is the object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
```

And in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public void register(@RequestBody UserEntity user) {
    user.save(); // how to do this?
}
```

Is there a simple way to save this object directly to my database? What would be the most direct way to do that above?

Comment: inject UserEntity repository to controller and persist. I think it's most direct way.

Comment: @AlexanderPolozov thanks -- I'm new obviously to the Spring framework -- would you mind showing an example of how to do that?

Comment: Well, there are many ways to do this. I think you should pay attention to documentation. If you already know how work with JPA it's shouldn't take many time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding data to RequestBody (415 error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218595/binding-data-to-requestbody-415-error)

Answer (score 4):

You can by using Repository, just need to create Repository interface.
some thing like that

```
public interface UserEntityRepositoryextends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserEntity ,Long>
```

and inject the Repository

```
@Autowired
UserEntityRepository userEntityRepository ;
```

then save

```
  userEntityRepository.save(user)
```